# Is volatile not needed for objects' members but only on primitive members?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

My Code is

```
package threadrelated;
import threadrelated.lockrelated.MyNonBlockingQueue;

public class VolatileTester extends Thread {

 MyNonBlockingQueue mbq ;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    VolatileTester vt = new VolatileTester();
    vt.mbq = new MyNonBlockingQueue(10);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+vt.mbq);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(vt,"First");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(vt,"Secondz");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+vt.mbq);

}
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" before    "+mbq);
    mbq = new MyNonBlockingQueue(20);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" after   "+mbq);
}

}
```

Output is

```
main threadrelated.lockrelated.MyNonBlockingQueue@72fcb1f4
Secondz before    threadrelated.lockrelated.MyNonBlockingQueue@72fcb1f4
First before    threadrelated.lockrelated.MyNonBlockingQueue@72fcb1f4
Secondz after   threadrelated.lockrelated.MyNonBlockingQueue@7100650c
First after   threadrelated.lockrelated.MyNonBlockingQueue@7100650c
main threadrelated.lockrelated.MyNonBlockingQueue@7100650c
```

It shows that when First thread assigns member variable to new object, same is visible to other thread. Even if "mbq" is not declared as volatile.

I used breakpoints to try different sequence of operations. But my observation is that one thread can immediately see impact of other thread.

Is volatile not needed for class members which are object ? Are they always synchronized to main memory ? Volatile needed only for primitive member variables (int, long, boolean etc. ? )

Comment: Do you want code that happens to work when you try it or code that is guaranteed to work by the standard?

Comment: "guaranteed" :)

Comment: @shmosel sorry. copy paste error. Added missing line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just as necessary for references as it is for primitives. The fact that your output doesn't show a visibility problem doesn't *prove* one doesn't exist. In general, it's very difficult to prove non-existence of a concurrency bug. But here's a simple counterproof showing the necessity of `volatile`:

```
public class Test {
    static volatile Object ref;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // spin until ref is updated
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (ref == null);
            System.out.println("done");
        }).start();

        // wait a second, then update ref
        new Thread(() -> {
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) {}
            ref = new Object();
        }).start();
    }
}
```

This program runs for a second, then prints "done". Remove `volatile` and it won't terminate because the first thread never sees the updated `ref` value. (Disclaimer: As with any concurrency test, results may vary.)

Comment: Does this example require multiple cores/processors?

Comment: @BasilBourque I've only tried on my own machine, so I can't say for sure. Does it not work for you?

Comment: I mean in general. I wonder if the visibility issue being demonstrated by your example code is a non-issue on a single core machine? Or might the threads see different visibility on a single core because of CPU caches?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not a useful test of volatile. It will work with or without volatile, not by accident but according to spec.

[Shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44039346/217324) includes code that is a much better test of the volatile keyword because there is a consequence to whether the field is volatile or not. If you take that code, making the field non-volatile, and insert a println within the loop, then you should see the field's value set from the other thread be visible. This is because the println synchronizes on the print stream, inserting a memory barrier.

There are two other things in your example that insert these barriers, causing updates to be visible across threads.
The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) lists these happens-before relationships:

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.
>
> All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join() on that thread.

This means volatile is not needed in your posted code. The newly started threads can see the queue passed in from main, and main can see the reference to the queue once the threads have completed. There is a window, between the time the threads start and the time a println is executed, where the contents of the field could be stale, but nothing in the code is testing it.

But no, it's not accurate to say volatile isn't needed for references. There's a happens-before relationship for volatile:

> A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.

The spec doesn't distinguish between fields that contain references and fields that contain primitives, the rule applies to both. This comes back to Java being call-by-value, references are values.

Comment: The changes are happening within thread execution i.e. after both threads are started. So I did not understand the the point you highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the fact that you do not see something happening at this point in time, does not mean it will not happen later. *Especially* true for concurrent code. There is `jcstress` library that you can play with and will try to show you what might be wrong with your code.

Volatile variable is different than other variables because it introduces `memory barries` at the CPU level. Without these there is no guarantee of *when* or *what* thread sees the updates from another. In simplistic words these are called `StoreLoad|StoreStore|LoadLoad|LoadStore`.

So using volatile guarantees visibility effects, actually it is the only thing you can rely on for visibility effects (besides using `Unsafe` and locks/synchronized keyword). You also have to take into consideration that you are testing this for *a particular CPU*, most likely `x86`. But for different CPU's (like ARM let's say) things would break much faster.